# How to quit the `mg` editor?

Tags: linux, emacs, editors, bsd

I tried to use one of my Git aliases and accidentally opened the `mg` editor. I tried a lof of different keys and nothing seemed to close it. I eventually just used <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> to to send it to the background and then killed it with `kill %1`.

After that I went to check the manpages https://linux.die.net/man/1/mg, but the only quit related commands don't seem to do much:

```
C-g' keyboard-quit
C-x C-g' keyboard-quit
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but how can it be closed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so I'm not sure what the `'` means here, but pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> actually worked:

```
C-x C-c' save-buffers-kill-emacs
```

> `save-buffers-kill-emacs`
> Offer to save modified buffers and quit mg.

Comment: The apostrophe is just dodgy formatting on the web site you’re looking at; [properly-formatted versions of the `mg` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/mg/mg.1) don’t have them (look at `man mg` on your system too).

Comment: Ty! Yeah `man mg` doesn't show that :)